# Serving static files with nginx, available through browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, nginx

I have a server set up using `nginx` to serve static files (used by two apps, one Django and the other AngularJS). My concern is the following:

If someone navigates to [Example Domain](http://example.com/static/js/app.js) (or any other static file) they can see its contents. For some reason it feels like bad practice to me that users can find all my stuff (if they know the URL or care enough to figure it out). Is this a legitimate concern or am I just being paranoid?

If this is a legitimate concern, is there a way to make it so that my server can serve my Django and AngularJS apps without the static files being visible through a browser?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. All you can do is obfuscate it.

Comment: That makes sense. So I guess if I have code that I don't want others to see (a trade secret or the like), it's best to find a way to execute that kind of logic on the back end?

Comment: Well you can output Javascript code on the server for e.g people who are logged in and who are authorized to view it